# javascript - .replace() is working on one string but not another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pulling data with AJAX, into an array, everuthing there works fine, then I have this...

```
$.each(data, function (key, value){ 
            var add = value[5]+value[6];
            var sub = add.replace(" ","");
            var link = 'http://'+sub+'.mydomain.com';
}

//OUTPUT: http://RR1 Box 22USHIGHWAY 67.NextHomeTown.com
```

This isn't working.  It's not replacing any space characters.

Now, here's where it gets fun.  This works on every other DB entry that is returned that has a space.  Crazy, right?

Is there some type of character encoding that might be causing it not to recognize the space character that is used in this particular entry?  The MySQL table has them entered as `varchar`, but at this point in the process, they're both just text strings right?  So it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Can you dump the values into the console and also dump `typeof add` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will only replace the first spacebar it will match. Use this to replace all spacebars:

```
var sub = add.replace(/\s/g,"");
```

Comment: True, but he said it's not replacing *any* spacebars, so the core problem should be something else.

Comment: If it wouldn't be a String, there should accur an error instead of an continue. Maybe there was an extra spacebar in the String which he missed.

Comment: I can think of a few reasons why no error would show, but yes, the easiest answer would be yours. Let's see what tPlummer says.

Answer (score 0):

Since you report the desired behaviour with other tables, it's perhaps not relevant - but don't forget that in javascript, the string replace function only replaces the *first instance* of the searchString, *unless* you use a regular expression.

```
"red, red, red".replace(/ /g, "");
"red,red,red"

"red, red, red".replace(" ", "");
"red,red, red"
```